# opposite to "go to declaration" in phpstorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

When I use phpstorm I often use "Go to declaration" by pressing CTRL and left mouse click. This takes me to the method declaration in the class. Thats fine but few moments later I want to scroll back where I just clicked declared method.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to scroll back where I just looked or I need to always remember to bookmark a view before I click "Go to declaration"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Ctrl+Alt+<left arrow>`

....................

Comment: I just did like what you said .. and My SONY VAIO display got turned upside down !

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran: for me it additionally bakes muffins :-D

Comment: Damn , wish I had your brand ! ^_^

Comment: Nice one , zerk ! **PHPStorm** team need to fix my issue though :)

Comment: Just a small note. This shortcut is actually "navigate back" which works in 95% situations. Good enough for me

Answer (score 2):

@zerkms anwser is OK but if you have intelHD (intel3000 or something similar  graphic card you will need to disable rotating screen shortcuts (or just change them).

This is how to do it:

- press **CTRL+ALT+F12**(to open up HDIntel Utility)
- select **Options**
- and then choose shortcuts for rotating screen or just turn off all of them

Answer (score 0):

**You can find this setting in:**
Settings -> Keymap -> Main menu -> Navigate -> **Back**

**Default shortcuts are:**
Mouse Button4 click
Ctrl + Alt + Left (if not working, [check your window manager settings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180634/why-phpstorm-hotkeys-ctraltleft-shiftf6-not-works-with-xfce4-desktop-envir))

I personally use "opposite" shortcut of "Declaration (Main menu -> navigate -> Declaration):
Ctrl + Button 3 (right) click  (but you have to click at line cursor is on)